# Custom PHP/JS Analytics Solution issue

Tags: javascript, ajax

Ok, here's an example of the Google Analytics code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'userIDhere']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageLoadTime']);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

My question is this. I'm building a system to allow for a basic analytics style script to be placed on different sites like the above Google Analytics code, but I'm not sure how to retrieve the values that are sent and query  the database. Should I even query a database? Maybe a text based solution is better? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first step I would take would be to develop a deep understanding of how the different analytics solutions accomplish visitor tracking.  And the first problem that needs to be solved is getting usage data from the visitors browser to your server.

Google Analytics accomplishes this by requesting an "invisible .gif" and appending all the data as query parameters on this request.  You can read about the details here:  https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsTrackingOverview

The second problem to solve is visitor identity: tracking multiple visits and pageviews as a single visitor.  Again, Google Analytics accomplishes this through first party cookies, which you can read about in more detail here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsCookies

Of course neither of these considerations address what you will actually do with the data once you collect it, and the short answer there is that yes, I believe you will need a database, as a text based solution (I am thinking you mean something like server logs) would be inadequate for data retrieval.